# Doctrine QueryBuilder How to do that

Tags: doctrine, query-builder

This is in symfony.
How to do it better this work on one env on other doesn't don't know why
r. is Recruitment Entity which has onetomany relation to RecruitmentUsers

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->select('r')
        ->addSelect('(SELECT SUM(b.payedAmount) FROM APP\Entity\RecruitmentUsers b WHERE b.isActive = 1 and r.id = b.recruitment) as payedSum')
        ->addSelect('(SELECT SUM(c.declaredAmount) FROM APP\Entity\RecruitmentUsers c WHERE c.isActive = 1 and r.id = c.recruitment) as declaredSum')
        ->leftJoin('r.recruitmentUsers','u')
        ->groupBy('r.id')
        ->orderBy('r.id', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
```

In dev env everything works fine in prod i got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: SELECT r, (SELECT SUM(b.payedAmount) FROM APP\Entity\RecruitmentUsers b WHERE b.isActive = 1 and r.id = b.recruitment) as payedSum, (SELECT SUM(c.declaredAmount) FROM APP\Entity\RecruitmentUsers c WHERE c.isActive = 1 and r.id = c.recruitment) as declaredSum FROM App\Entity\Recruitment r LEFT JOIN r.recruitmentUsers u GROUP BY r.id ORDER BY r.id DESC in /usr/home/eliteinvestments/domains/4eliteinvestments.pl/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:43 Stack trace: #0 /usr/home/eliteinvestments/domains/4eliteinvestments.pl/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(487): Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::dqlError('SELECT r, (SELE...') #1 /usr/home/eliteinvestments/domains/4eliteinvestments.pl/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(987): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->semanticalError('line 0, col 42 ...', Array) #2 /usr/home/eliteinvestments/domains/4eliteinvestments.pl/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1 in /usr/home/eliteinvestments/domains/4eliteinvestments.pl/templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error.html.twig on line 6
```

I done cache:clear, cache:warmup, doctrine:cache:clear-query, doctrine:cache:clear-result, doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
none of it works.
Any hints ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this. Not entirely sure what you want tho.

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('r')
->select('r.id, SUM(u.payedAmount), SUM(u.declaredAmount)')
->leftJoin('r.recruitmentUsers','u')
->where('u.isActive = 1')
->groupBy('r.id')
->orderBy('r.id', 'DESC')
->getQuery()
->getResult();
```